# Can't upgrade ubuntu version from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.10

I tried to upgrade my ubuntu version by following command, but got an error like this:

```
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

this is the way that I tried

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Btw the upgrade button on software updater not working

I appreciate in advance

Comment: First of all, the question that is linked is actually asking a different (yet related) question. Secondly, the answers there didn't resolve the issue for me. I have `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` installed, and I still get the same "Your Ubuntu release is not supported" error.